# npm package vulnerability not fixing

Tags: javascript, security, npm, yarnpkg

I run `yarn audit --level high` and the result came with 10 vulnerability packages found

```
┌───────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ high          │ Prototype Pollution                                          │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Package       │ dot-prop                                                     │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Patched in    │ >=4.2.1 <5.0.0 || >=5.1.1                                    │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Dependency of │ pwmetrics                                                    │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Path          │ pwmetrics > lighthouse > configstore > dot-prop              │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ More info     │ https://www.npmjs.com/advisories/1213                        │
└───────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

more...
```

then i update the package to `pwmetrics@4.2.3` version, then did same audit check but still its showing same result.

Comment: *then i update the package* how exactly are you doing this?

Comment: Upgrading pwmetrics (which is deprecated by the way) does not necessarily upgrade lighthouse and does not necessarily upgrade configstore and does not necessarily upgrade dot-prop. Check the dependency tree including the semantic versioning ranges.

Comment: The "patched in" versions refer to the dot-prop package, not to the pwmetrics package.